# Log additional information with TranscriptLoggerMiddleware

Tags: botframework

I'm using TranscriptLoggerMiddleware to log transcript to Azure blobs.
Now, I want to add additional information to the activity, for example, account ID.

Ideally I want the account ID to be the top level folder when creating the blobs so one can easily locate all conversations for a given account.

The logger is only passed the activity without any context. So I'm looking at the **Entities** activity property which I can potentially use for storing my account ID.

Is this a valid approach?
Any other ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: I have struggled with this as well. I tried building my own custom logger as well but I run into issues with the account information being overwritten. I did set up a function in the onTurn handler to grab the transcript (on delay) and add additional information, but that has the risk of not working due to concurrency issue and has not been reliable. It is also using CosmosDB for storage instead of Azure Blob. That's the best I've found so far.

Comment: I just implemented the idea I described and it worked. I use Entities field on IActivity and store whatever information I need there, then in the custom logger I can extract it and thus no need to pass context to the logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.
This worked for me:

```
public class SetEntityMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly BotState _userState;
    private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<UserProfileState> _userProfileState;

    public SetEntityMiddleware(UserState userState)
    {
        _userState = userState;
        _userProfileState = userState.CreateProperty<UserProfileState>(nameof(UserProfileState));
    }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var userProfile = await _userProfileState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfileState(), cancellationToken);
        this.SetEntity(turnContext.Activity, userProfile);

        turnContext.OnSendActivities(async (ctx, activities, nextSend) =>
        {
            var userProfile = await _userProfileState.GetAsync(ctx, () => new UserProfileState(), cancellationToken);

            foreach (var activity in activities)
            {
                this.SetEntity(activity, userProfile);
            }

            return await nextSend().ConfigureAwait(false);
        });

        await next(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private void SetEntity(Activity activity, UserProfileState userProfile)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.AccountNumber))
        {
            var entity = new Entity();
            entity.Type = "userProfile";
            entity.Properties["accountNumber"] = userProfile.AccountNumber;

            if (activity.Entities == null)
            {
                activity.Entities = new List<Entity>();
            }

            activity.Entities.Add(entity);
        }
    }
}
```